# Under which conditions does Malliavin derivative and Lebesgue integral commute?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

So the title is quite self-explanatory,

suppose we have a stochastic process $(X_t: t\in[0,T])$ where for a fixed $t$, $X_t$ is a $\mathbb R$-valued square integrable random variable, we could even assume it's in the Gaussian Sobolev space $\mathbb D^{1,2}$.
Then in which cases does the following hold?

$$D_u \int_0^t b(s,X_s)ds= \int_0^t D_u[b(s,X_s)]ds$$

where $D_u$ stands for the Malliavin derivative at time $u$.

I tried searching for this in Nualarts book, but I haven't found a proof, or the necessary conditions. Furthermore this seems to be done quite often when dealings with SDEs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could this help, or are you just in search of a reference to cite? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549240/interchanging-malliavin-derivative-with-lebesgue-integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypotheses are sometimes stated differently, depending on the kind of processes you have in mind. The following is taken from Pratelli's [lecture notes](https://people.dm.unipi.it/pratelli/Didattica/Appunti-Malliavin.pdf), Theorem 3.2.1, but he gives no further reference.

**Theorem.** Let $(X_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ be a stochastic process such that for all $0\leq t \leq T$ we have $X_t \in \mathbb D^{1,2}$; also suppose that there is a measurable version of $D_sX_t$ on $\Omega \times [0,T] \times [0,T]$ such that $\int_0^T \| X_t \|_{\mathbb D^{1,2}}^2\, \mathrm{d}t<+\infty$. Then $\int_0^T X_t\, \mathrm{d}t$ is in $\mathbb D^{1,2}$ and $$D_s \int_0^T X_t\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^T D_sX_t\,\mathrm{d}t$$ for a.e. $0 \leq s \leq T$.

The proof only needs the following fact.

**Lemma.** We have $F \in \mathbb D^{1,2}$ and $DF=Z$, iff $F \in L^2(\Omega)$ and there is $Z \in L^2(\Omega \times [0,T])$ such that, for any smooth functional $G$ and any square-integrable $h$, the following equation holds:
$$\mathbb E \left [\left (\int _0^T Z_s h(s)\, \mathrm{d}s \right )G  \right] = \mathbb E \left [ -FD_h G + FGW(h) \right]. $$
This makes the usual integration by parts into a characterization of the Malliavin derivative (compare with Lemma 1.2.2 of Nualart). You can find a proof in Chapter 5 of Bogachev's *[Gaussian Measures](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-62)*.

With this, the proof of the Theorem is easy. Take the equation
$$\mathbb E \left [\left (\int _0^T D_sX_t h(s)\, \mathrm{d}s \right )G  \right] = \mathbb E \left [ -X_tD_h G + X_tGW(h) \right],$$
then integrate with respect to $t$ and interchange integrals (Fubini+Cauchy-Schwarz) to get
$$\mathbb E \left [\left (\int _0^T \left ( \int_0^T D_sX_t \, \mathrm{d}t \right) h(s)\, \mathrm{d}s \right )G  \right] = \mathbb E \left [  \left ( -\int_0^T X_t \, \mathrm{d}t \right)D_h G + \left ( \int_0^T X_t \, \mathrm{d}t \right)GW(h) \right].$$
You can then apply the Lemma again, since $\int_0^T X_t \, \mathrm{d}t$ is in $L^2$, which tells you exactly that
$$D_s \int_0^T X_t\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^T D_sX_t\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

I imagine that you cannot find a precise reference since most works that study applications are not particularly concerned with precise statements, and the proof is not hard anyway.

Comment: this is a very nice way to prove it! I don't know why I was expecting something quite involved, but this is a straightforward consequence of the integration by parts. By the way is this a set of notes of some course? If yes from which university? I also live in Italy and I didn't know Pratelli

Comment: I think that the approximation argument from the linked MSE post is the most straightforward low-tech approach, since it doesn't need the Lemma I quoted. The notes are from a course Pratelli (who works mostly on this stuff and mathematical finance) taught at the University of Pisa some years ago, I couldn't find the course page and thus the references for the content (which is surely well-known if not folklore). I'd guess since Da Prato also works in Pisa you might have some luck searching through his books on the topic.